# Calculate max, average of some row sql

Tags: sql, max, average

i've a table like:

[image]

i have to make sql query to get the average of `v` and order the average to have the #n best name in function of v in time. Users so have to select #n of best that want to have before do this query.

In order to have:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need average, you need SUM

```
SELECT name, SUM(v) AS sum FROM table GROUP BY name ORDER BY SUM(v) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select name, sum(v) as average
from table
group by name
order by sum(v) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(average),name from tableName group by name order by avg(average) desc
```